# Angular CLI 10 ng build --prod emits empty lines

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli, angular10, tfs-2012

When building angular app using CLI if we use `ng build --prod` it will emit **2** empty lines, and if I remove `--prod` , these empty lines are gone.

[image]

On my dev environment, it's very minor but when I am trying to build app via **TFS these empty lines causing build failure**.

[image]

My application is new application created with `ng new <appname>`

Environment Details :-

```
Angular CLI: 10.0.5
Node: 12.18.1
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 10.0.9
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.1000.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.1000.5
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.1000.5
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.1000.5
@angular-devkit/core              10.0.5
@angular-devkit/schematics        10.0.5
@angular/cli                      10.0.5
@ngtools/webpack                  10.0.5
@schematics/angular               10.0.5
@schematics/update                0.1000.5
rxjs                              6.5.5
typescript                        3.9.7
webpack                           4.43.0
```

How to remove these empty lines .. any idea ?

**This issue is not occurring in  Angular CLI: 7.1.4**

Comment: What is the build step that marks this as failed?

Comment: @Igor, I have added angular commands as a separate bat file. and executed in Post-Build section.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like issue in Angular CLI, created issue in  [github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/18524)